# Django celery gives me a (13, 'Permission Denied')

Tags: django, amqp, celery

I'm using django celery in one of my projects and I'm receiving a (13, Permisison denied) error.

See below for the traceback:

```
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
        resp = view_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/var/www/html/django/congressticketing/order/views.py in checkout
      task = create_order.delay(total=(total+shipping_price), cart=cart, shipping_method=shipping_method, form=form) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/task/base.py in delay
        return self.apply_async(args, kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/task/base.py in apply_async
        return apply_async(self, args, kwargs, **options) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/messaging.py in _inner
            return fun(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/execute/__init__.py in apply_async
                                              exchange_type=exchange_type) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/task/base.py in get_publisher
                             routing_key=self.routing_key) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/messaging.py in __init__
            consumers = get_consumer_set(self.connection) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/celery-2.1.4-py2.4.egg/celery/messaging.py in get_consumer_set
                            backend=cset.backend, **queue_options) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/messaging.py in __init__
            self.declare() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/messaging.py in declare
                                       warn_if_exists=self.warn_if_exists) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/backends/pyamqplib.py in queue_declare
        return self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue, ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/backends/pyamqplib.py in channel
            connection = self.connection.connection ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/connection.py in connection
            self._connection = self._establish_connection() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/connection.py in _establish_connection
        return self.create_backend().establish_connection() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/carrot-0.10.7-py2.4.egg/carrot/backends/pyamqplib.py in establish_connection
                          connect_timeout=conninfo.connect_timeout) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/amqplib-0.6.1-py2.4.egg/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py in __init__
            self.transport = create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/amqplib-0.6.1-py2.4.egg/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py in create_transport
        return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/amqplib-0.6.1-py2.4.egg/amqplib/client_0_8/transport.py in __init__
            self.sock.connect((host, port))
```

I assume it has something to do with permissions.  The login credentials to the server are fine, everything works except this.

The celeryd daemon runs fine with the rabbitmq connection credentials I've given it.

It doesn't give me this error when I run the development server as root.  I assume it might have something to do with file or socket permissions, but I don't know where to go to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I'm running RHEL5 SELinux.  Be sure to follow the instructions at the bottom of the following page: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied